# No manual entry for fcntl problem

Tags: manual, manpage, fcntl

When I use `man fcntl' got the message:

```
No manual entry for fcntl
```

which the pkg is needed to install?

ps. I use debian.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In Debian these man pages are available in manpages-dev package.

Answer (score 0):

This doesn't answer your question directly, but: I myself just use the internet: here is the [first search result](http://www.manpagez.com/man/2/fcntl/) for "man fcntl" [in google](http://www.google.com/search?q=man+fcntl&ie=utf-8&oe=utf-8&aq=t&rls=com.ubuntu:en-US:unofficial&client=firefox-a).

Answer (score 0):

`fcntl` is a standard C library function so it should be one of your development packages. However, I long ago gave up on using man on the UNIX boxes themselves, try typing "man fcntl" into Google (with the quotes) to get online versions.

Just don't do this to try and figure out how `man` itself works. Typing "man man" into Google returns some interesting results (not safe for work).